# Sorting with Power BI Using Direct Query

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table visual. I am using Direct Query, NOT import mode.

Originally, I had my months sorting alphabetically (April, August, December, etc, like this), but I wanted them to sort by Month Number, AFTER sorting by year in the visual.

I tried to be clever by concatenating the month number to the month name, so that the values look like this:

```
01 - January
02 - February
...
09 - September
10 - October
11 - November
12 - December
```

To the left of this month_name column, I have a year column. I want the data to be sorted, ascending, by year, and then by the month column I created.

How can I do this in my table?